# empty_graph() error message when creating NetworkX Graph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am getting the following error message out of Python:

> empty_graph() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Even though I went through all websites I could find the problem does not solve. I created a correlation matrix(thus the graph edges should be weighted) from a dtasetand then defined a panda edgelist to create the graph. I used he following code:

```
corr  = input_data.corr()
df = corr.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['source', 'target', 'weight']
df = df[df['weight'] != 0]
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', ['weight'])
```

The panda_edgelist looks the following way:

```
source  target  weight
AUT     AUT     1.0
AUT     BEL     0.9915461015887707
AUT     BGR     0.8833592506356065
AUT     CHE     0.8338789009282549
... and so on...
```

Here is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in  g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'source','target','weight', nx.DiGraph)
>
> File "C:.\convert_matrix.py", line 323, in from_pandas_edgelist g = nx.empty_graph(0, create_using)
>
> File "", line 2, in empty_graph
>
> File "C:.\utils\decorators.py", line 287, in _nodes_or_number iter_wa = iter(which_args)
>
> TypeError: empty_graph() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately not, I also tried ```g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'source','target', edge_attr = 'weight')``` but it did not help.

Comment: Actually, using your small input data here, your code is working.  I would recommneding, breaking you input dataframe up to see what data is failing.  Print (df) after you filter from weights.

Comment: Your code works fine on my system. Maybe you want to pass the 5th argument, e.g, `g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', 'weight', nx.DiGraph)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond. Unfortunately ```g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'source','target','weight', nx.DiGraph)``` is not working either. I also excluded all weights smaller than 0 from the dataframe ```df = df[~(df['weight'] <= 0)]``` however I am still getting the same error message. The error comes with the information ```in _nodes_or_number iter_wa = iter(which_args)``` . I checked the source and target dataframe.into(). It tells me to be a ```non-null object```. Does it maybe has to be defined in an other way? Thank you guy again!

Comment: It will be easier to diagnose with the full error message.  That will include things like telling us exactly what line of the code is producing that error message.

Comment: @Joel: ```g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'source','target','weight', nx.DiGraph)
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<ipython-input-229-cc7e1ea1c0a4>", line 1, in <module> g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'source','target','weight', nx.DiGraph) File "C:\.\convert_matrix.py", line 323, in from_pandas_edgelist g = nx.empty_graph(0, create_using) File "<C:\.\decorator.py:decorator-gen-10>", line 2, in empty_graph File "C:\.\utils\decorators.py", line 287, in _nodes_or_number
    iter_wa = iter(which_args) TypeError: empty_graph() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given```

Comment: Hi - I've tried to put your error message into the question.  Please check the formatting.

Comment: Can you provide code to generate a sample of df so we can troubleshoot? also just to confirm, your trouble is in producing the graph yes?

Comment: This looks like it should work.  If at all possible provide the code Wboy requests.  Also, could you tell us what version of networkx and python you are using?